# How do resolution functions within promise constructors work inside of a setTimeout on the event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm working on some event loop knowledge refinement and I'm a bit stumped at the following code block:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log('in here, 1')
  setTimeout(() => resolve(3),0);
  console.log('in here, 2')
}).then((val) => console.log(val));

new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log('in here, 5')
  resolve(4)
  console.log('in here, 6')
}).then((val) => console.log(val));

//in here, 1
//in here, 2
//in here, 5
//in here, 6
//4
//3
```

I understand that the `Promise` constructor returns a new `Promise` instance *synchronously*; that the code inside of the executor function in a `Promise` constructor runs *synchronously*; that `.then()` returns a new `Promise` instance *synchronously*; but that the `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` handlers in a `.then((onFulfilled, onRejected) => {})` are invoked *asynchronously*.

I have a few questions regarding the `resolve` within the `setTimeout` in the first `promise`. The callback function in the `setTimeout` will resolve the promise with the value of `3`. However, since callbacks from `promises` are placed in the microtask queue, and in this case, the `.then()` will place a `(val) => console.log(val)` on the microtask queue, why can it read the value of the resolved `promise` it's attached to? The `resolve` is in the timers callback queue which hasn't been processed by the event loop yet because we're inside of the microtask queue. Thus, shouldn't the value read by the `.then()` callback in the first `promise` be `undefined`? I may be misunderstanding how `resolve` exactly works in the executor in the constructor.

I could use some clarification on this and maybe on how the microtask queue works in Node. Thank you.

Comment: The `.then()` callback function isn't called until the corresponding `resolve()` is called. At that time, it receives the argument that was passed to `resolve()`.

Answer (score 0):

> the `.then()` will place a `(val) => console.log(val)` on the microtask queue

No, it won't. The `.then()` method does that only for already-settled promises. But if the promise has not yet been resolved, all it does is to register the handler callback in a list on the promise object, to be fired when the promise is fulfilled.

> Why can it read the value of the resolved promise it's attached to? Shouldn't the value read by the `.then()` callback in the first promise be `undefined`?

There seems to be a misunderstanding here that `then` somehow "reads" a value. It can't, when the value is not available yet, and it doesn't actively "wait" for the value either. [Just like when using any asynchronous callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), it registers a handler to be called later by the code that provides the result - in the case of an pending promise, it is the `resolve(3)` call that fulfills the promise and places the tasks to run the promise handlers on the microtask queue. This scheduling does not happen until `resolve` is actually called, which in your example occurs in a function on the timers queue, but it might happen at any time later or even never.

Answer (score 0):

The `then` callback is only queued once the promise on which it is called is fulfilled. So in the first block of your code this is not happening immediately, but as the promise implementation logic receives the value to resolve with, it can queue the job for executing the callback **and** the argument to pass to that callback.

Here is a simplified time line of what happens in terms of callstack, actions (both JS and non-JS) and queues:

| JS call stack | Action | macrotask queue | promise job queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| script | `new Promise`: constructor creates promise 1 and calls the given callback | - | - |
| script > promise constructor callback | `console.log` outputs "in here, 1" | - | - |
| script > promise constructor callback | `setTimeout` registers the given callback | - | - |
| script > promise constructor callback | `console.log` outputs "in here, 2" | - | - |
| script | `new Promise()` evaluates to the created promise 1 (pending) | - | - |
| script | `.then` creates promise 2 and registers the given callback | - | - |
| script | `.then()` evaluates to promise 2 (ignored, pending) | - | - |
| script | `new Promise`: constructor creates promise 3 and calls the given callback | - | - |
| script > promise constructor callback | `console.log` outputs "in here, 5" | - | - |
| script > promise constructor callback | `resolve` fulfils promise 3 with value 4 | - | - |
| script > promise constructor callback | `console.log` outputs "in here, 6" | - | - |
| script | `new Promise()` evaluates to the created promise 3 (fulfilled) | - | - |
| script | `.then` creates promise 4 and seeing promise 3 is fulfilled it puts the given callback in the promise job queue with 4 as bound argument | - | resolve promise 4 using `(val=4) => console.log(val)` |
| script | `.then()` evaluates to promise 4 (pending, ignored) | - | resolve promise 4 using `(val=4) => console.log(val)` |
| - | JS engine monitors the job queues | - | resolve promise 4 using `(val=4) => console.log(val)` |
| job | The job *resolve promise 4 using* `(val=4) => console.log(val)` is pulled and executed | - | - |
| job | `console.log(4)` outputs "4" | - | - |
| job | Promise 4 is fulfulled with value `undefined` | - | - |
| - | JS engine monitors the job queues | - | - |
| - | `setTimeout` implementation detects timer expired (this could have happened earlier, but the effect is the same) | - | - |
| - | `setTimeout` implementation puts a job in a macrotask queue | `() => resolve(3)` | - |
| - | JS engine monitors the job queues | `() => resolve(3)` | - |
| - | JS engine pulls `() => resolve(3)` from macrotask queue and executes it | - | - |
| job | `resolve(3)` fulfils promise 1 to value 3 | - | - |
| job | Promise implementation puts `then` callback in promise job queue with 3 as bound argument | - | resolve promise 2 using `(val=3) => console.log(val)` |
| - | JS engine monitors the job queues | - | resolve promise 2 using `(val=3) => console.log(val)` |
| job | The job *resolve promise 2 using* `(val=3) => console.log(val)` is pulled and executed | - | - |
| job | `console.log(3)` outputs "3" | - | - |
| job | Promise 2 is fulfulled with value `undefined` | - | - |
| - | JS engine monitors the job queues | - | - |